# Multiple File Uploads Error using JQuery-File-Upload and Paperclip

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Following a [tutorial](https://github.com/fedesoria/fily/tree/no-asset-pipeline) on multiple file uploads in Rails using [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)   there seems to be a problem as soon as the attribute *:multiple => true* is added to the file_field e.g.

```
<%= f.file_field :path, :multiple => true %>
```

The following error occurs:

```
Started POST "/pictures" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-20 18:50:51 +0100
Processing by PicturesController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"hcMORNvY1Rx/tbHv8wB+hLKzS92Nez5qHdgHXfcq+Nc=", "picture"=>{"path"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fa183ba1a18 @original_filename="001.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture[path][]\"; filename=\"001.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/xq/dq4fkqnx0m36htfgdj2lxlb00000gn/T/RackMultipart20120620-60459-yeso39>>]}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError (No handler found for [#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fa183ba1a18 @original_filename="001.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture[path][]\"; filename=\"001.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/xq/dq4fkqnx0m36htfgdj2lxlb00000gn/T/RackMultipart20120620-60459-yeso39>>]):
app/controllers/pictures_controller.rb:14:in `create'
```

Has anyone come across a solution to this problem?

Rails: 3.2.5, Paperclip: 3.1.2, Browser: Chrome Version 19.0.1084.56, OS: Mac OS X 10.7.4

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing the same thing, but without the multiple => true for the file field.  You won't be able to select multiple images at a time with the file browser dialog, but so long as you're not using IE you can still drag-and-drop multiple files at a time and that works perfectly.

I haven't gotten multiple file selection in the dialog working, but it's only a minor issue once you get the rest of the setup working.